# assigning values to a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to do this numpy operation in tensorflow?

```
r[:,t,:] = x
```

In tensorflow, I see something called scatter_nd but it seems to only work on the initial dimensions. For eg,

```
r[t,:,:] = x
```

I believe can be written as :

```
scatter_nd(r, [[t]], x)
```

Comment: Do you actually want to create a tensor from scratch (initializing only a slice of it) or do you want to update the slice of an existing tensor?

Comment: Is it possible to just update the tensor?

Comment: You can create one that sandwiches one slice of update between two slices of old tensor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be very easy to solve it using scatter_nd since it is very hard to form the updates. But this can be relatively easy if you use stack and unstack like this:

```
In [67]: embd = np.tile(np.expand_dims(np.arange(40).reshape([-1, 10]), axis=2), (1, 1, 4))
In [68]: embd_np = copy.copy(embd)
In [69]: embd_np[:, 2, :] = np.ones([4, 4])
In [70]: embd_tf = tf.stack([j if i != 2 else tf.ones([4, 4], dtype=tf.int64) for i, j in enumerate(tf.unstack(tf.constant(embd), axis=1))], 1).eval()
In [71]: embd_np == embd_tf
```